# Convert pandas DataFrame to record array without the extra column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test_array = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], 
                      dtype={'names': ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'formats': ('f8', 'f8', 'f8')})
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(test_array)
test_df.to_records().view(np.float64).reshape(test_array.shape + (-1, ))
```

I expect a view on the original `test_array` to be returned, with shape `(2, 3)`, however, I get this `(2, 4)` array.

```
rec.array([[0.e+000, 1.e+000, 2.e+000, 3.e+000],
           [5.e-324, 4.e+000, 5.e+000, 6.e+000]],
          dtype=float64)
```

Where did the extra column, column 0, come from?

Edit: I've just learned I can use `DataFrame.values()` to do the same thing, but I remain curious why this behavior exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_records` is capturing the index too. Note that this is stated in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html):

> Index will be included as the first field of the record array if requested

If you want to exlude it simply set `index=False`.

---

Although in your case you can simply use [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) (or `values`):

```
test_df.to_numpy().view(np.float64).reshape(test_array.shape + (-1, ))

array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

Comment: This is a bit of a contrived example, but I have some code that expects a record array because it uses the dtype names internally. Is there a way to do this and maintain those values.

Comment: Oh! I missed this before. I had created a separate function to remove the index and apparently it didn't work very well.

Comment: So perhaps you could go with `to_records` setting `index=False`? @mnosefish

Answer (score 4):

If you need a record array, use [`np.rec.fromrecords`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromrecords.html):

```
np.rec.fromrecords(test_df, names=[*test_df])
# rec.array([(1., 2., 3.), (4., 5., 6.)],
#          dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

My tests show that this is faster than `df.to_records` by some.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `index=False` in `to_records`:

`test_df.to_records(index=False).view(np.float64).reshape(test_array.shape + (-1, ))`